# Integrating Google Sign-In and Facebook Login into same activity in android Studio

Tags: android

I need to integrate both `Facebook` and `Google Plus` in the same activity but I'm not getting success in it. I have tried both in individual projects and they work fine but when I add both projects together my app gets crashed. Even I have tried them with custom buttons too but they don't work either. Currently my `Google` part is working fine but I get error when I click on `Facebook`'s button at the time of login

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what error you're facing and how you have coded so it's a little tough to help on code terms but, why don't you try [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?gclid=CjwKCAjw8-LnBRAyEiwA6eUMGpSxWgWedwawciIahBJ5IoxSwa4F6jGmv5hzcsX_X5Ow3Vy-0L3wGxoCBEwQAvD_BwE%E2%80%8E), here's a guide as well https://medium.com/@ckullo/android-login-using-firebase-auth-entication-533272d1a419 from Medium, and still if you want to do it without OAuth then [this](https://medium.com/@official_ceo/guides-on-how-to-use-facebook-login-kit-on-android-apps-3593892c82) may help from Medium as well.

Hope it helps!